Bayes factor for hypothesis
I am studying Bayesian hypothesis testing and I want to calculate the Bayes factor for
\begin{align*}
H_0:  \lambda = 1  \hspace{0.2cm} vs  \hspace{0.2cm}  H_1:\lambda >  2
\end{align*}
with $p(\textbf{x}| \lambda) \sim P(\lambda)$ and $\lambda \sim Exp(1)$.
I think it should be
$$
B_{01} = \frac{p(\textbf{x}| \lambda = 1)}{\int_{\lambda > 2} p(\textbf{x}|\lambda) p(\lambda) } =  \frac{e^{-n}}{\int_{2}^{\infty} \lambda^{n \overline{x}} e^{-\lambda(n+1)} d \lambda }
$$
and reject $H_0$if
$$
B_{01} \leq \frac{P(H_1)}{P(H_0)}
$$
is this correct? I'm just starting out with Bayesian hypothesis testing, is there a good book or page that has many examples? greetings
